# How to create a customer for woo-commerce website in android application?

Tags: android, woocommerce

I did all the connection with woo commerce, my product and all things are fetch properly, but when i create a customer it gives me a error of missing parameter data.

```
aQuery = new AQuery(context);

HashMap<String, String> stringStringHashMap = new HashMap<>();
String url = WooCommerceAuthentication.getUrl("POST&", "customers", stringStringHashMap);

AjaxCallback<JSONObject> cb = new AjaxCallback<JSONObject>() {

    @Override
    public void callback(String url, JSONObject jsonObject, AjaxStatus status) {
        System.out.println(jsonObject);
    }
};

String data = "{\n" +
        "\t\"customer\": {\n" +
        "\t\t\"email\": \"myddemaideelo@gmail.com\"}}";
JSONObject jsonObject = null;
try {
    jsonObject = new JSONObject(data);
} catch (JSONException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

cb.header("Accept", "application/json");
cb.header("Content-Type", "application/json");
cb.header("User-Agent", "WooCommerce API Client-PHP/2.0.1");

Map<String, Object> params = new HashMap<String, Object>();
params.put("method", "POST");
params.put("data", "chandan24892@gmail.com");

cb.params(params);

aQuery.ajax(url, JSONObject.class, cb);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your customer information you are submitting is incomplete. As per the documentation [here](https://woothemes.github.io/woocommerce-rest-api-docs/#create-a-customer), customer fields should be as,

```
  "customer": {
    "email": "john.doe@example.com",
    "first_name": "John",
    "last_name": "Doe",
    "username": "john.doe",
    "billing_address": {
      "first_name": "John",
      "last_name": "Doe",
      "company": "",
      "address_1": "969 Market",
      "address_2": "",
      "city": "San Francisco",
      "state": "CA",
      "postcode": "94103",
      "country": "US",
      "email": "john.doe@example.com",
      "phone": "(555) 555-5555"
    },
    "shipping_address": {
      "first_name": "John",
      "last_name": "Doe",
      "company": "",
      "address_1": "969 Market",
      "address_2": "",
      "city": "San Francisco",
      "state": "CA",
      "postcode": "94103",
      "country": "US"
    }
  }
```